# Analysing .NET Module files (.netmodule)

Tags: .net, clr, cil, netmodules

How can I analyse a .NET module?

I know I can open it in a hex reader and work from there, but it's not exactly a friendly way of going about things.

Is there an ILDasm-like tool available?

Comment: What are you looking for that ILDasm doesn't do for you? You could take a look at [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). "ILSpy is the open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler."

Comment: ildasm.exe can do it, did you try?

Comment: @rickvdbosch ILDasm, ILSpy and dotPeek are for assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant Aye, ILDasm supports `exe`, `dll`, `mod`, `mdl` and `winmd`.

Comment: @HansPassant Turns out, it does work if you launch it from the command line.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of another way to launch an .exe.  "From the GUI" is possible, I added to Tools > External tools.

Comment: @HansPassant I mean it as opposed to using the File -> Open menu in ILDasm.

Answer (score 2):

ILDasm does work, if you launch it from the command line (`ILDAsm myModule.netmodule`) rather than from the GUI.